# How to create .pot files with POedit?

Tags: theme-development, translation, localization

I've spent hours today on what seemed like something really simple, which is to create a .pot file for a Wordpress theme that I'm creating. I've read the [Smashing Magazine article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/29/internationalizing-localizing-wordpress-theme/), the [Tutsplus article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/translating-your-theme--wp-25014) and few others on how to use [Poedit](http://poedit.net/) to create .pot files for a theme, and then create .mo and .po files, but sadly, I'm still stuck at the first step.

I installed Poedit and I find that the UI is completely different than that is shown in all of the the tutorials and it seems like there is no more an option to create .pot file. Only thing that is available is to create .po and .mo files from an existing .pot file, which is not what I need now.

So can someone please tell me how can I create .pot files using Poedit or with some other method, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Try [Creating POT Files](https://codex.wordpress.org/User:Skippy/Creating_POT_Files).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may try [Eazy Po](http://www.eazypo.ca).

- From file menu select “New from source code files..”.
- In xgettext Command Manager window; Press “Browse folder” to select base source folder.
- In Build pane press “Execute Command” button to generate Pot file.

Comment: Much better and easier than POEdit. Clean UI. Has all the i18n translation functions in the keyword list by default. Thank you.

Comment: Used this after realizing that POEdit's WordPress features are paid. Worked perfectly!

Comment: Worked perfectly for me too and easier, very easier than poedit.

Comment: Not available for linux :(

Comment: Not anymore up-to-date, consider using WP CLI.

Answer (score 56):

I found the easiest way now is to use the [WP-CLI](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/installing/). Navigate to your theme or plugin and execute the following command (after WP-CLI is installed):

```
wp i18n make-pot . languages/my.pot
```

(See [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/i18n/make-pot/) of the command)

You can then edit this file with Poedit or any other handy translation tool.

Comment: this should be the new accepted answer

Comment: I had to add the `--ignore-domain` switch to the end of the command in order to get all `__` (and friends) added to the `.pot` file because the text domain in my plugin is dynamically generated. This adds the plugin header stuff as well as the strings needed for translation into the `.pot`

Comment: THE best and simplest way imo

Comment: This is the most easiest and best and free way to generate pot file. It should be the top answer.

Comment: This is the most up-to-date answer because WP CLI is the solution to everything. No more messing another workaround while there is an official and documented way.

Answer (score 44):

Here is how you can create a .pot file for your theme with Poedit (free edition, version 1.6.10) on OS X.

Best practise is to save language files in a folder named "languages" in your theme directory. If you haven't already, create it before you start.

In Poedit:

1. In the "File" menu select "New"
2. Select the language that you used in your theme (probably English)
3. In the "Catalog" menu select "Properties"
4. Enter the project information in the "Translation properties" tab
5. Go to the 3rd tab "Sources keywords"
6. Click on the "New item" button (2nd button) and enter a keyword and repeat this for each of your keywords (`__`, `_e`, `esc_attr_e`, etc.)
7. Click on the "OK" button at the bottom
8. In the "File" menu select "Save As.."
9. Save the file as "yourthemename.pot" in the "languages" folder in your theme directory (make sure you add the .pot extension to the filename because by default it will save as .po)
10. In the "Catalog" menu select "Properties" again
11. Go to the 2nd tab "Sources paths"
12. Set the value for "Base path" to `../` (the .pot file is saved in a subdirectory so this way you set the base to the parent directory, ie. your theme directory)
13. Next to "Path" click on the "New item" button and enter `.` (this will make it scan your theme directory and its subdirectories)
14. Click on the "OK" button at the bottom
15. In the project window click on "Update" (2nd icon at the top)
16. In the "File" menu click "Save"

And you're done :)

Comment: This does not work for WordPress and the specific changes to the translation system. It is incomplete at best.

Comment: It worked really well for my plugin

Comment: It works for the plugin, but doesnt translate the plugin description from header

Comment: PoEdit (the free version) doesn't give the option to save a new file as a .pot file

Answer (score 27):

You can do this with the WordPress tools, without POEdit.

First, do an svn checkout of http://develop.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/:

`svn co http://develop.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/ wpdev`

Then, switch to the i18n tools directory in it:

`cd wpdev/tools/i18n/`

Then just run the makepot.php over your theme's directory:

`php makepot.php wp-theme /path/to/your/theme themename.pot`

This will create a themename.pot file for you. Use it in any standard translating tool you like.

This is better because it uses the WordPress code to find the i18n functions, so you won't miss any of them. Additionally, it will find and add things like the theme header information, such as the name, description, etc. This allows for those to be translated too. Make sure you include the "Text Domain:" header in your style.css for those to work.

Comment: will this work for a plugin too?

Comment: Yes, just use "wp-plugin" instead of "wp-theme" and it will generate a POT file for a plugin.

Comment: Every other method that does not use the WordPress specific tools is broken in some way.

Comment: Awesome tools! Though it kept throwing errors like "Couldn't generate file" even though I `chmod +x` the directories..

Comment: Why would chmod +x help? Maybe you should try making the directory writable instead of executable.

Comment: Thanks Otto, I didn't get notified of that, but now I am on Ubuntu and this works rather perfect!

Comment: Followed the same steps, translated everything but unbale to translate the plugin description in the header section of the plugin.

Comment: If you're translating a plugin, make sure you use "wp-plugin" in the command so that it knows what headers to look for.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop external tools altogether with [Loco Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) plugin. I've tried it about a year ago and never used POEdit since. Install it on your test site and create POT file with one click.

Comment: This does not work for WordPress and the specific changes to the translation system. It is incomplete at best.

Comment: Woot? It's a WP plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who had like to use Poedit instead of Easy Po.

1. [Download](https://poedit.net/download) (latest version of) Poedit and Install
2. Go to file>New. A new tab will come up, choose your language of translation and Save (ctrl + s) to the root folder of your wordpress theme.
3. On the page you will see next, Click on - "Extract from sources". The tab you will see next is similar to those used in the links you pasted. "Project Info" is now "Translation Properties", as well as "Paths" and "Keywords" are "Sources Paths" and "Sources keywords" respectively

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, the solution is in the first tab when you extract catalog, should put UTF8 recommanded, and in the 3th tab "Sources keywords", click on the "New item" button (2nd button) and enter a keyword and repeat this for each of your keywords (__, _e).

Answer (score 0):

**As [Otto said](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/169282/6332) :**

**For Mac users**, I would do something like :

- After installed by `svn co http://develop.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/ wpdev`

**So...**

- Make `/languages/` dir on your theme
- Make a command file like `lang.command` in that `/languages/` dir
- Inside `lang.command`

add code something like this..

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $(dirname "$0")
php /Users/YOUNAME/wpdev/tools/i18n/makepot.php wp-theme ../../mytheme mytheme.pot
```

**PS:** Change your correct **makepot.php** path and **mytheme** to your theme name

Now everytime you want to make a new **.POT** file, you can just ran **lang.command**

[image: dir]

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution to create .pot files for folks who prefer NPM is [wp-pot](https://github.com/wp-pot/wp-pot). It comes with a bunch of options that you can tweak to your liking. Super simple to set up.

Answer (score -1):

Try this post: [Create a .pot or .po File using Poedit](http://betterwp.net/wordpress-tips/create-pot-file-using-poedit/). It describes the workflow, and indicates .po and .pot files are the same.

> By default Poedit saves your file as a .po file but since the two files are identical you can get around that by simply choosing to save the .po file as a .pot file

Comment: This does not work for WordPress and the specific changes to the translation system. It is incomplete at best.

Answer (score -1):

## Script auto create .po file, auto add all text from you code

1. Add load_theme_textdomain('my-textdomain',**DIR**.'/languages/');
2. Create folder wp-content/themes/MY_THEME/languages (add your language .mo file to this folder)
3. Create **po.php** and add this script:

```html
<?php /*Script by Sien.com.vn */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

require(''.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php' );

function title_p($title) {

$title='Po create';   

return $title;}
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'title_p' );


$robots_p='noindex,nofollow';   

get_header();  

echo '<div id="content" class="col col-100">';

if(current_user_can('manage_options')){

function write_txt($path,$content,$type){
$file=fopen($path,$type) or die();
fwrite($file,$content);
fclose($file);
return TRUE;
}

if(isset($_POST['lang'])){
$lang_code=pathinfo($_POST['lang'],PATHINFO_FILENAME);

load_textdomain('this_lang',__DIR__.'/'.$lang_code.'.mo');


$textdomain=$_POST['textdomain'];


$txt='';

function sfile($dir, $ext) {
    global $textdomain;

$globFiles = glob("$dir".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."*.$ext");
$globDirs = glob("$dir/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);

foreach ($globDirs as $dir) {
sfile($dir, $ext);

}

foreach ($globFiles as $file=>$path) {

$txt.=file_get_contents($path,FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

}


preg_match_all('/__\(\'(.+?)\',\''.$textdomain.'\'\)/',$txt,$output);


$arr=array();

foreach(array_unique($output[1]) as $v){

    if(isset($v)){
write_txt(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat',''.$v.'**$!3|\\/**','a+');
    }
}

}
sfile(get_template_directory(),'php');


$get=file_get_contents(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat');

$k=explode('**$!3|\\/**',$get);


foreach(array_unique($k) as $v){
    
    if(!empty($v)){ 
    
if($v==__($v,'this_lang')){
write_txt(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat.empty','
msgid "'.$v.'"
msgstr ""
','a+');
}else{
write_txt(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat.isset','
msgid "'.$v.'"
msgstr "'.__($v,'this_lang').'"
','a+');
}
        
    }

    }
    
if(empty(file_get_contents(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat.isset')) && empty(file_get_contents(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat.empty'))){
        echo '<div class="error">Error, Textdomain <b>'.$textdomain.'</b> not found!</div>';
    }else{

write_txt(''.__DIR__.'/'.$lang_code.'.po','# '.$lang_code.' LANG
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"PO-Revision-Date: 2017-11-23 22:26+0700\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=1; plural=0;\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.0.4\n"
"Language: vi_VN\n"
"Project-Id-Version: Sien\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: \n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"


'.file_get_contents(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat.isset').'
'.file_get_contents(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat.empty').'
','w+');
    

echo '<div class="success"><span style="color:blue">Success</span> -> Saved to: '.__DIR__.'/ <b>'.$lang_code.'.po</b></div>';

unlink(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat');
unlink(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat.isset');
unlink(''.__DIR__.'/po.dat.empty');

}

}


echo '<form action="" method="POST">
<div class="menu bd text-center"><p>Language: <select name="lang">';

foreach(glob("".__DIR__."/*.mo") as $path) {echo '<option value="'.$path.'">'.pathinfo($path,PATHINFO_FILENAME).'</option>';}

echo '</select></p>';

$txt='';
function stext($dir, $ext) {
$globFiles = glob("$dir".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."*.$ext");
$globDirs = glob("$dir/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach ($globDirs as $dir) {stext($dir, $ext);}

foreach ($globFiles as $file=>$path) {
    if($path!=__FILE__){
$txt.=(str_replace(' ','',file_get_contents($path,FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH)));
    }

}

preg_match_all('/load_theme_textdomain\((\'|\")(.+?)(\'|\")/',$txt,$gtextdomain);
$td='';
foreach($gtextdomain[2] as $text){
    
    if(!empty($text)){
    $td.='<option value="'.$text.'">'.$text.'</option>';
    }


}

write_txt(__DIR__.'/textdomain.dat',$td,'a+');
}
stext(get_template_directory(),'php');

$textdomain=file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/textdomain.dat');
if(empty($textdomain)){echo '<div class="error">Not found textdomain [ <b>load_theme_textdomain ("you-textdomain","path_to_language_folder");</b> ]</div>';}else{
echo '<p>Textdomain: <select name="textdomain">'.$textdomain.'</select></p>';
}

echo '<p>
<input type="submit" value="Create new.po file"/>
</p>
</div>
</form>';

unlink(__DIR__.'/textdomain.dat');

}

echo '</div>';

get_footer();
```

4. Go to **youdomain/wp-content/themes/MY_THEME/languages/po.php** and create .po file
5. Copy **wp-content/themes/MY_THEME/languages/[LANG].po** to desktop and open with **Poedit** -> Compile MO -> copy [LANG].mo to **languages** folder

Use as **echo __('This text','you-textdomain');**

Comment: There is no sense on doing so, while there are cli tools already doing the magic, consider using WP CLI for the win.